# Is this a New or Faulty collision system?

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, collision

I am making a top down 2D game with box collisions. Essentially this code just *iterates* through all pixels *left* to check for "Collision". If *none move* box. I have **not seen anyone else** do this so I am wondering. What could be ***faulty*** with this system?

```
if (keyLeft)
{
  var canMove = true;
  for(var x = 0; x < 64; x++){
    var tile = this._world.getTile(new Vector2(this._position.x - 2, this._position.y + x));
    if(tile != undefined){
      if(tile.material.isCollidable == true){
        canMove = false;
        this._hsp = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  if (canMove == true){
    this._position.x -= 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: they are my variables: this._hsp is the horizontal speed of the player.

Comment: this._world.getTile is just to check what object is at that pixel position. Latter in the code it checks if that object is collidable .

Comment: tile.material.isCollidable is to check if the block, or "tile" that is in a specified pixel position is collidable.

Comment: It seems like you're iterating over blocks left-to-right. If the player is moving left, shouldn't you check right-to-left in order to get the first block with which the player would collide? Also, why are you adding the x-coordinate to the y position? Also, it doesn't seem like you're checking if the player collides with the block at all (unless when pressing left the player moves as far left as possible), but rather just that there exists a collidable block on that path.

Comment: My box is 64 pixels by 64 pixels.

Comment: I could only figure out how to find collisions at a certain pixel position

Comment: So when I press the left key I iterate though all of the pixels two pixels to the left of the box. This is done by starting at the top left and making its way down the y axis until all of the pixels are checked.

Comment: I am also open to any new ways for checking top down collisions.

Comment: Ah, I see. Still, unless I'm misunderstanding something, it seems like you should not be adding to the y-coordinate. Pressing left means you are moving in the x-direction, not at all in the y-direction.

Comment: Basically I have a box and I want to move left. I check to see if any pixels on a line parallel to the boxes left side are collidable. I have tried not doing it this way and just checking one of the pixels to the left of the box. This resulted in the boxes lower portion able to glide right over solid object while the program only checked to see if the top left was colliding.

Comment: In that case, you need to supply more of your code and ask a more specific question in order to get useful help.